# Flask in VS Code: No module named website.__main__; 'website' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I have a very basic flask website, as shown below in the file `website.py`. Everything works, unless I set `debug=True` and then set a breakpoint in visual studio, then I get the above error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'hi'
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a debug configuration for your flask python file:

> In the launch.json file click `Add Configuration` -> select `Python`
> -> select `Flask`.
>
> And remember to rename the `app.py` to `website.py`

Or you can copy this in your launch.json file directly, and select this as the configuration for your debugging:

```
{
  "name": "Python: Flask",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "module": "flask",
  "env": { "FLASK_APP": "website.py", "FLASK_ENV": "development" },
  "args": ["run", "--no-debugger"],
  "jinja": true
},
```

And you can have a look at the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_run-the-app-in-the-debugger) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Flask recommends running the application by using `flask run` command. See the [Quick start documentation on Flask website for Flask 2.0.x](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/). To run the application using debug mode, set `FLASK_ENV` environment variable to `development`.

`website.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'hi'
```

If you are using `Linux/Mac`:

```
export FLASK_APP=website
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

If you are using `Windows`:

```
set FLASK_APP=website
set FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

#### Update for Flask 2.3 onwards

`FLASK_ENV=development` is deprecated from Flask 2.3 onwards.
Either Use `FLASK_DEBUG=1` or use `--debug` flag in `flask run` command: `flask run --debug`.

**References:**

- [Quick start documentation on Flask website for Flask 2.0.x](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/)

Comment: FLASK_ENV=development is deprecated from Flask 2.3 onwards. Use FLASK_DEBUG=1 instead.